# Installer installing .NET framework 4 Client Profile even though project targets 3.5 Client Profile

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I have a project that I've created in VS 2010. It initially targeted the 4.0 Client Profile framework but I've changed it so it now targets the 3.5 Client Profile framework. Mainly because most of my users will have it installed.

However, when I publish it and run the installer on another machine, it insists on downloading the 4.0 framework client profile.

Any suggestions?

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the project properties : Publish -> Prerequisites and check the version of the framework that you want installed.

[image]